# PHP - Change Content on Form Submit - Upload

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, authentication

On Successful upload, i would like to replace the form used to upload the file with a thumbnail of the uploaded file. Is this possible?

```
if uploaded = yes

show file

if uploaded = no

show form
```

Based on Codeigniter & Ion Auth

Regards,

Comment: cannot accept a question because never found a solution :(

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']))

$image = $_FILES['file'];

echo '<img src="uploads/'.$file.'">';

else {

form here

}
```

You would then need the appropriate code to move the uploaded file from the temp to the location.

Comment: $_FILES['file'] what would be the name of file? what i have in my controller? my file names take the form of userid_filename.jpg

Comment: Yes correct, so the 'file' would be whatever you set in the form for the controller to be as you said and then you would need to move the file into uploads and set a name which would be $file.

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have following input box for uploading file

```
<input name="logo" id="logo" class="input" type="file">
```

now you can access this as following way,

```
if($_FILES['logo']['name']!='')
{
         echo "file is uploaded do whatever you want with it";
}
else
{
           echo "error";
}
```

I hope you get it

### test.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        if($_FILES['userfile']['name']!='')
        {
            echo "fine";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "not fine";
        }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="30" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have an undefined index on 'logo' as it were.

Comment: <?php
if($_FILES['userfile']['name']!='')
{

echo 'image uploaded preview etc img';

}
else {

$this->load->view('uploadform.tpl.php');

}
?>

Comment: what is the name or id of your input box, that you use to upload file? does 'userfile' is the name and id your input box?

Comment: it is yes <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="30" />

Comment: safe i changed ['name']!='userfile' and image was displayed, though still undefined index on userfile

Comment: i have run one example in my server, i have attached code of that file in in my answer (i have edited the answer), look at the below section in my answer i have write code for test.php

Comment: Example: page loads with no errors but no show on content. Neither fine or not fine comes up.

Comment: would it not be easier to add a hidden form field to the upload to set uploaded to either yes or no and display content based on that?

Comment: in this example, when you browse and upload any file and press submit button, nothing displayed? i mean fine or not fine?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6236/discussion-between-jon-and-manoj-nakum)

Answer (score 0):

if(!$_POST['submit']) {

echo "";

(Your form goes here)

```
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"upload\">
```

}else {

(if they press submit it will auto take them to this section)
(it is here where you put your INSERT into database script)

(it is also here where you would echo the picture)